# Infinitely many exceptional divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Does there exist a smooth, complex, projective 3-fold, with infinitely many divisors isomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^{2}$ which have normal bundle $\mathcal{O}(-1)$?

Comment: Exercise 1.8 in my advisor's notes http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/utah-notes.pdf explains how to construct a surface with infinitely many $K_X$-negative extremal rays, although I'm not sure off the top of my head if these are actually $(-1)$-curves. Perhaps you could use a similar elliptic threefold construction?